# Excel VBA - FilterMonth with Select Case

Tags: vba, excel

I have a combo box with the below code.

It filters a table with invisible dropdowns after a month selection. It works without any problems but I think the code is pretty bad.

How can it be optimized?

Also it should be always the month of the current year. Actually they are all manually defined.  (APR = "4/30/2017")
Isn't something like just "April" with the AutoFilter possible?

Thanks for any advice!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    With Me.FilterMonth

    .Clear
    .AddItem "January"
    .AddItem "February"
    .AddItem "March"
    .AddItem "April"
    .AddItem "May"
    .AddItem "June"
    .AddItem "July"
    .AddItem "August"
    .AddItem "September"
    .AddItem "October"
    .AddItem "November"
    .AddItem "December"
     .ListIndex = -1
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub FilterMonth_Change()
Select Case FilterMonth.Value

    Case "January"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim JAN As String
        JAN = "1/31/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, JAN), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "February"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim FEB As String
        FEB = "2/28/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, FEB), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "March"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim MRZ As String
        MRZ = "3/31/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, MRZ), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "April"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim APR As String
        APR = "4/30/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, APR), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "May"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim MAI As String
        MAI = "5/31/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, MAI), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "June"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim JUN As String
        JUN = "6/30/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, JUN), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "July"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim JUL As String
        JUL = "7/31/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, JUL), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "August"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim AUG As String
        AUG = "8/31/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, AUG), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "September"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim SEP As String
        SEP = "9/30/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, SEP), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "October"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim OKT As String
        OKT = "10/31/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, OKT), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "November"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim NOV As String
        NOV = "11/30/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, NOV), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Case "December"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim DEZ As String
        DEZ = "12/31/2017"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, DEZ), VisibleDropDown:=False
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This belongs on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review. Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim i As Integer
    With Me.FilterMonth
        .Clear
        For i = 1 To 12
            .AddItem Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), i, 1), "mmmm")
        Next i
        .ListIndex = -1
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub FilterMonth_Change()
    Dim iMonth As Integer, sCriteria As String
    iMonth = FilterMonth.ListIndex + 1 ' Selected Month (first item is index zero)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' End of selected Month: Use 1st of next month of current year then subtract 1 day
    sCriteria = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), iMonth + 1, 1) - 1, "m/d/yyyy") ' Or change to the format of your data
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, sCriteria), VisibleDropDown:=False
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```